# Binding SwipeView in CollectionView In xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind SwipeView text but it is showing me nothing and other Buttons outside of the collectionview are binding correctly. when i am debugging the code then all values is showing in model class but it is not updating the UI controls Text inside collection view. I am sharing my code.Thanks in advance.

---view code--

```
                       <CollectionView x:Name="ColView" ItemsSource="{Binding BindProductList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalOptions="Start">

                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <SwipeView>

                                    <SwipeView.RightItems >

                                       
                                        <SwipeItems >

                                            <SwipeItem x:Name="BtnDelete" Text="{Binding BindActionButtons.BtnDelete}" BackgroundColor="Red" 
                                                       Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand,Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                            <SwipeItem x:Name="BtnEdit" Text="{Binding BindActionButtons.BtnEdit}" BackgroundColor="Green"
                                                       Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditCommand,Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                        </SwipeItems>



                                    </SwipeView.RightItems>


                                    <Frame x:Name="s" OutlineColor="Silver" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5,5,25,5">

                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20,5,-20,5">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                          
                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                               FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                               Padding="-50,0,0,0"></Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                               Text="{Binding Quantity}" Padding="-40,0,0,0"></Label>

                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" 
                                               Text="{Binding VendorName}" Padding="-40,0,0,0"></Label>

                                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"
                                               Margin="0,0,2,0" Text="{Binding ReceivingDate,StringFormat='{0:M/d/yy}'}" 
                                               Padding="-25,0,-15,0"></Label>

                                        </Grid>

                                    </Frame>

                                </SwipeView>

                               




                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

---- model class---

```
 public class ActionButtonsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string btnSave;
     
    public string BtnSave
    { 
        get { return GlobalMethods.ChangeLang(); } 
        set 
        {
            //if (btnSave != value)
            //{
                btnSave = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BtnSave));
            //}
        }  
    }

    public string BtnUpdate { get { return GlobalMethods.ChangeLang(); } }
    public string BtnDelete { get { return GlobalMethods.ChangeLang(); } }


    private string btnEdit;
     
    public string  BtnEdit
    {
        get { return GlobalMethods.ChangeLang(); }
        set
        {
          //  if (btnEdit != value)
           // {
                btnEdit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BtnEdit));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BtnSave));

           // }
        }
    }

    public string BtnClear { get { return GlobalMethods.ChangeLang(); } }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }



}
```

-- view model code--

```
 private ActionButtonsModel bindActionButtons = new ActionButtonsModel();
   
    public ActionButtonsModel BindActionButtons
    {
        get { return bindActionButtons; }
        set
        {
            //if (bindActionButtons != value)
           // {
                bindActionButtons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindActionButtons));
           // }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to bind SwipeView text but it is showing me nothing and other Buttons outside of the collectionview are binding correctly.

Your SwipeItem `Text="{Binding BindActionButtons.BtnDelete}"` has some problem.

Please take a look the following code about SwipeItem text binding.

```
 <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem
                                    x:Name="BtnDelete"
                                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=BindingContext.BindActionButtons.BtnDelete, Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}" />
                                <SwipeItem
                                    x:Name="BtnEdit"
                                    BackgroundColor="Green"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=BindingContext.BindActionButtons.BtnEdit, Source={x:Reference Name=ColView}}" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
```

The viewmodel.cs:

```
 public partial class Page7 : ContentPage
{
    public Page7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new Colviewmodel();
    }
}

public class Colviewmodel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> BindProductList { get; set; }
    public ActionButtonsModel BindActionButtons { get; set; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; }
    public Colviewmodel()
    {
        BindProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product(){ProductName="product 1",Quantity="12",VendorName="vendor 1",ReceivingDate=new DateTime(2021,4,13)},
            new Product(){ProductName="product 2",Quantity="12",VendorName="vendor 2",ReceivingDate=new DateTime(2021,4,13)},
            new Product(){ProductName="product 3",Quantity="12",VendorName="vendor 3",ReceivingDate=new DateTime(2021,4,13)},
            new Product(){ProductName="product 4",Quantity="12",VendorName="vendor 4",ReceivingDate=new DateTime(2021,4,13)},
        };

        BindActionButtons = new ActionButtonsModel()
        {
            BtnDelete="delete data",BtnEdit="edit data"
        };
    }
}

public class ActionButtonsModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _BtnDelete;

    public string BtnDelete
    {
        get { return _BtnDelete; }
        set
        {
            _BtnDelete = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BtnDelete");
        }
    }
    private string _BtnEdit;

    public string BtnEdit
    {
        get { return _BtnEdit; }
        set
        {
            _BtnEdit = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BtnEdit");
        }
    }
}
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivingDate { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot sir for helping